# How does one disable third party keyboards in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Basically that's it, I haven't found a way to disable third party keyboard in my app, although I know it's possible 'cos I've seen it in apps like 1Password.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is only possible for password privacy fields. Is that what you're using it for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this code in your `AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: String) -> Bool {
    if extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

[Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623122-application).

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 5.0**

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
    return extensionPointIdentifier != UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier.keyboard
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {
  return extensionPointIdentifier != .keyboard
}
```